# NestJS - TypeORM - Unable to track the Entity Not Found in TypeOrm & Nest.JS

Tags: node.js, nestjs, typeorm

```
No repository for "UserEntity" was found. Looks like 
this entity is not registered in current "default" connection? +114ms
RepositoryNotFoundError: No repository for "UserEntity" was found. Looks like this entity is not registered in current "default" connection?
    at RepositoryNotFoundError.TypeORMError [as constructor] (E:\Projects\...\src\error\TypeORMError.ts:7:9)
```

This is a Seed Method. It runs fine and add the data in the database, after adding data, I just get the error.

```
import { MediaEntity } from '../entities/media.entity';
import { Connection, Equal } from 'typeorm';
import { UserEntity } from '../entities/user.entity';
import { Helper } from '../services/helper';

export default async function UsersSeed(connection: Connection) {
  const repository = connection.getRepository(UserEntity);

  const data: Partial<UserEntity> = {
    firstName: 'tesFName',
    lastName: 'testLNsmr',
    password: 'fafafa',
    email: 'testmail@mail.com',
    createdAt: Helper.dateToUTC(new Date())
  };

  let user = await repository.findOne({ email: data.email });

  console.log("19");
  console.log(user);

  if (!user) {
    const entity = Helper.createEntity(UserEntity, data);
    console.log("23");
    user = await repository.save(entity);
    console.log("25");
  } else {
    console.log("27");
    await repository.update(user.id, {
      firstName: data.firstName,
      lastName: data.lastName
    });

    console.log("33");
  }

  console.log("36");

  const mediaRepository = connection.getRepository(MediaEntity);
  await mediaRepository.update({ user: Equal(null) }, { user: user });

  return user;
}
```

A bit more context:
It is being imported in app.module.ts as this.

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    ServeStaticModule.forRoot({
      rootPath: join(__dirname, 'uploads')
    }),
    TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
      useFactory: async (optionsService: OptionsService) =>
        optionsService.typeOrmOptions(),
      imports: [OptionsModule],
      inject: [OptionsService]
    }),
    OptionsModule,
    MediaModule,
    AuthModule,
    PlaceModule,
    RepositoryModule,
    ServicesModule
  ],
  controllers: [],
  providers: []
})
```

And then there is src/entities/entities.module.ts as:

```
const entities = [
  UserEntity,
  MediaEntity,
  PlaceEntity,
  DownloadRestrictionEntity,
  MediaInfoEntity
];

@Module({
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature(entities)],
  exports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature(entities)]
})
export class EntitiesModule {
}
```

Then src/options/options.service.ts as

```
@Injectable()
export class OptionsService {
  constructor(
    private service: ConfigService<IEnvironmentVariables>
  ) {
  }
 public typeOrmOptions(): TypeOrmModuleOptions {
    const environment = process.env.NODE_ENV ? process.env.NODE_ENV : '';
    const directory = this.directory();
    return {
      type: 'postgres',

      host: this.service.get('POSTGRES_HOST'),
      port: this.service.get('POSTGRES_PORT'),
      username: this.service.get('POSTGRES_USER'),
      password: this.service.get('POSTGRES_PASSWORD'),
      database: this.service.get('POSTGRES_DATABASE'),
      synchronize: false,
      migrationsRun: this.service.get('RUN_MIGRATIONS'),
      keepConnectionAlive: this.isTest(),

      entities: [`${directory}/**/*.entity${environment ? '{.ts,.js}' : '{.js, .ts}'}`],

      migrationsTableName: 'migrations',
      migrations: [`${directory}/migrations/*.ts`],

      cli: {
        migrationsDir: 'src/migrations'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: We need a bit more context, I assume you are using `TypeOrmModule` provided by `@nestjs/typeorm`? for the config, which probably looks something like this`TypeOrmModule.forRoot({ entities: [] })`, how are you importing entities? 

Usually this is where this problem lies, `TypeOrmModule` doesn't know where to look for the entity or can't find in the given location the entity for which you need the repository in you application (that you are most likely using in a service somewhere)
`

Comment: @Vin_it thanks for the insight, I have added more context, let me know if there is something else needed.

Comment: Thanks for updating, I would suggest checking this line `${directory}/**/*.entity${environment ? '{.ts,.js}' : '{.js, .ts}'}` again, I have seen this happen a few times and this is the culprit almost always (the other is to forget to add `@Entity`) 

Also, this path is affected by where you are starting the app from so consider that as well

Comment: Thank you, it worked, my environment  variable was empty, so it was searching for .js and I have .ts files since I am in development environment

Comment: Ah yes, I should have mentioned it. We had an exact same issue recently. Glad it is working!

Answer (score 0):

please create **UserRepository** [typeorm-repository-pattern](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/database#repository-pattern)
**Method 1:**

```
@Injectable()
export class UsersService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(User)
    private usersRepository: Repository<User>,
  ) {}
}
```

**Method 2:** use **BaseRepository** from [typeorm-transactional-cls-hooked](https://github.com/odavid/typeorm-transactional-cls-hooked)

```
@EntityRepository(UserAdminEntity)
export class UserAdminRepository extends BaseRepository<UserAdminEntity> {}
```

Comment: UserRepository is already available via Method1